# setting styleName attribute in ui.xml overwrites primaryStyleName set in constructor of widget

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I've written a custom widget with its own set of styles. These styles are defined in a little resource interface contained in the widget, and applied in the constructor of the widget.

I'd like to use the widget in a uibinder xml file, and apply additional styles there.  Unfortunately, setting the styleName attribute seems to remove the styles applied in the constructor, and indeed the setStyleName javadoc indicates that it clears other style names.

What's the best solution here? I could override setStyleName, but that takes away options later.  Is there a way to call addStyleName instead of setStyleName from the ui.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `addStyleNames` in your ui binder file?

Comment: Somehow I didn't realize I could directly call functions. I just use an attribute like `addStyleNames="{style.whatever}"`?

Comment: I guess this is a special case.  `addStyleNames` doesn't show up in any auto-complete help and doesn't follow any convention, but does indeed work.  Some mention of it at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World